# Count number of Sundays that comes on first day of month

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can somebody write sql queries:

1. To print all Sundays between Jan 1, 1900 to Dec 31, 2000 that come on 1st day of month.
2. Count number of Sundays between Jan 1, 1900 to Dec 31, 2000 that come on 1st day of month.

Comment: Did you try anything already?

Comment: No..Cant think of anything..

Comment: You need to make an effort - even if it's really messed up. Show us that you tried. Otherwise, you won't learn anything here. I'll give you a hint - "numbers table" - but that's for the elegant solution. There's also a brute-force solution that I would expect any beginner should be able to come up with. Post something like that and I'll show you the elegant way. Hint 2: start with figuring out how to list ALL the dates in your range.

Comment: Do you have a table with all the dates in that range?

Comment: Another hint for you to look: [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms174420.aspx) and [DATENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Happy birthday, I was bored, this looked interesting to write, and it could be useful to someone else.  This isn't going to help you understand anything to have someone write the query for you, but this will give you the results you're looking for.

```
Declare @Date Table (N TinyInt Not Null)
Insert  @Date Values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)

Declare @Results Table (Date Date Not Null Primary Key Clustered)

Insert  @Results
Select  X.Date
From
(
    Select      Distinct Cast(DateAdd(Day, -(A.N + (10 * B.N) + (100 * C.N) + (1000 * D.N) + (5000 * E.N)), GetDate()) As Date) Date
    From        @Date   A
    Cross Join  @Date   B
    Cross Join  @Date   C
    Cross Join  @Date   D
    Cross Join  @Date   E
) X
Where X.Date Between '1900-01-01' And '2000-12-31'
And DatePart(WeekDay, X.Date) = 1
And DatePart(Day, X.Date) = 1

Select Date From @Results
Select Count(1) From @Results
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is rather easy. Knowing that January 1, 1900 was a Monday, we can start with January 7, the first Sunday in the range. Then we generate all following Sundays by adding 7 iteratively (or recursively for that matter) with a recursive cte till we get to December 31, 2000. Then we filter the data such that we only take those dates where the day of month is 1.

The recursion depth of SQL Server is limited to 100 by default. So we need to raise it. 101 years make little less than 5300 Sundays. Let's set a recursion depth of 5300 then.

```
with sundays ( sundaydate ) as
(
  select cast('1900-01-07' as date) as sundaydate
  union all
  select dateadd(day, 7, sundaydate) as sundaydate
  from sundays
  where sundaydate <= cast('2000-12-31' as date) 
)
select *
from sundays
where datepart(day, sundaydate) = 1
option (maxrecursion 5300);
```

Here is the SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/17317.

To only count the records instead, simply replace `select *` with `select count(*)`.